# Why do I need to compile a DLL with "-static" in order to unload it successfully

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, mingw-w64, compiler-flags

I was having issued using FreeLibrary to unload a DLL (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370375/dynamically-loading-dlls-error-after-returning-0-from-main) question for details). Basically the process was returning an exit code of 3 after calling FreeLibrary.

I looked at some other DLL projects that worked for me and realised that all the other DLLs were compiled with `-static`, which I tried, and it worked! I'm wondering why this flag might help the program to free the library from memory. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692128/static-option-for-gcc) question, specifically [Ahmed Masud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692187/4541936) (quoted below) it seems to me that all it does is forces the application (or DLL, in this case) not to be dependent on runtime linking of other libraries - is this right?

> The -static option links a program statically, in other words it does not require a dependency on dynamic libraries at runtime in order to run.

If so I'm not really sure why my DLL has to be linked with `-static` to work, as it doesn't depend on any runtime linking anyway. To make sure of this, I've created a test DLL with empty header and source files, and built (with *CMake 3.3* and *MinGW w64 4.0*) both versions:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -static")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Sure enough, compiling with the former allows my program to load and free the library successfully, but the latter causes an unkown error when I try to free the DLL. Thanks in advance for any insight into the matter.

---

### Test Application Code

```
int main() {
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("../lib/libComms.dll");

    if (hDLL) {
        cout << "DLL loaded"<< endl;
    }

    cout << "Attempting to free" << endl;

    //If I write a DllMain and place a breakpoint
    //in there, debugger shows error to occur on this line:
    auto res = FreeLibrary(hDLL);

    if (!res) {
        cout << "FreeLibrary failed with: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
} //Otherwise the issue only shows up after 'main' has returned
```

### DLL Code

**DLL.h**

```
#ifndef PROJECT_DLL_H_H
#define PROJECT_DLL_H_H



#endif //PROJECT_DLL_H_H
```

*And **DLL.cpp** is empty*
*The DLL source files are just the default generated by CLion.

### CMake File for DLL

```
project(SPOCK_Comms)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -static")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "F:\\SPOCK\\Roaming Server\\lib")

set(SOURCE_FILES DLL.h DLL.cpp)
add_library(Comms SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

### Output

**DLL Compiled without `-static`**:
[image]

**DLL Compiled with `-static`**:
[image]

Comment: Could you post exact sample code and build commands? I'd like to investigate this properly.

Comment: @rubenvb I've added all the source code along with the CMake file and output :) The only thing that changes in the build is the -static flag being added/removed

Comment: Maybe if you can write a working cpp code for your dll.

Comment: I do have a working DLL that actually does things (that's how I encountered the issue originally), however I made the empty DLL so that we could be sure that the DLL code itself wasn't causing the issue. Do you think it would be more helpful to have real DLL code?

Comment: I think so, maybe you can use the 2nd parameter, the **reason** one, debug messages from the dll itself.