# How can I check the dependencies required by a binary file in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, dependencies

I made a console application in C and is being readied for the first release.
I am sure that my binary depends on `libreadline-dev` due to using readline, but I can not identify the dependency behind the 2 following libraries: `libm.so.6 libc.so.6`

Which packages are the source of these 2 libraries? I suspect it must be something that shipped with gcc or came preinstalled on my Linux distro (Pop_OS! 21.04).
Also, how can I be sure that future versions of the dependencies won't break my app? Can I compile my app in a way where it would'nt need shared libraries?

Comment: It's unlikely you need libreadline-dev which is the headers needed for development.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this comment, but yes you are right it is only needed for compilation. Is readline also already bundled or should I list it as a dependency? @stark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check the dependencies required by a binary file in Linux?

Run `ldd <file>` - this will list all the dependencies of the binary, including dependencies-of-dependencies.

Example output:

```
$ ldd $(which ls)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe0c93d000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fa2abcd1000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa2ab8e0000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa2ab66e000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa2ab46a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa2ac11b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa2ab24b000)
```

---

> Which packages are the source of these 2 libraries?

`libm` and `libc` are both part of `glibc` - which comes bundled with virtually every Linux distro.

> Also, how can I be sure that future versions of the dependencies won't break my app?

On paper, you can't - and for non-standardized dependencies this is a real concern, and dependency management is a big problem that plagues many applications.

But specifically with regards to `libm` and `libc` - these are standardized libraries that are very likely to remain backwards-compatible in the future. Unless you're doing something very esoteric, I wouldn't worry.

The names `libm.so.6` and `libc.so.6` can be deceiving because of the `.6` suffix which might lead you to think that you're reliant on some "version 6" - but this is the suffix for historic reasons and has been constant for decades, it's very unlikely to change in future Linux distributions.

---

> Can I compile my app in a way where it wouldn't need shared libraries?

You can compile it as a **statically-linked** binary, with a command like `gcc -static...` - but this will bloat your binary and is not recommended unless you really need it.

Comment: Even if glibc is part of virtually every Linux distro, I still need to list it as a dependency right?

Comment: Yes, and for completeness you can even list a minimum version of `glibc` - you can run `apt depends <program>` and see that many programs list `glibc` as a dependency.

Comment: `-shared` to statically compile? I think you've mixed with `static.`... See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692187/1212012